# javascript regex to capture word in an html text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm explaining my issue.
I'm trying to do a javascript function to highlight words (change their color) in an html text. I have another function to un highlight them.

I have a list of keywords that i have to highlight.

Here is the code i've writed so far

```
function highlight_words(keywords) {

unHighlight_words(keywords);
$('.rubricContent').each(function(index, element) {
    //get elements for each rubrics
    var content = $(element).html();
    if (keywords) {
        $(keywords).each(function(i, e) {
            var term = e
            var re = new RegExp('(?:[^.;\w]|^|^\\W+){0}('+ term + ' )(?:[^.\w]|\\W(?=\\W+|$)|$){0}', "gmi");
            var subst = '<span style="color:red">' + term + '</span> ';
            content = content.replace(re, subst);

        });
        $(element).html(content);
    }
});
```

The result is not that bad my words are red colored but not when they are followed by a "." or a ","

Anyone have the solution for me ?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use \b word boundary as follows.

```
term='Test';
content='TestTest. Test Test: Test. Test, TESTtest'
var re = new RegExp('(\\b'+term+'\\b)', "gmi");
var subst = '<span style="color:red">' + term + '</span> ';

content = content.replace(re, subst);

alert(content)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3royvd66/1/